# How to check if column A row 1 and column B in row 1 has value true in pandas Datarame?

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe, excel-formula

how can i imitate following excel formula in python DataFrame? 
=IF(AND(A1=TRUE,B1=TRUE),TRUE,FALSE)

A           B             **C** 
TRUE      FALSE           **FALSE** 
TRUE      TRUE            **TRUE** 
FALSE     FALSE           **FALSE** 
FALSE     TRUE            **FALSE**

i tried this,
def check(sig1,sig2):
if sig1 == True and sig2 == True:
return True
else:
return False

df['chk'] = df.apply(check,df['up_signal1',df['up_signal2']],axis=1)

Comment: Btw in Excel, that can be simplified to `=AND(A1,B1)`.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. This seems like a rather basic question, have you done any research, read the Pandas documentation? See [ask], [help/on-topic].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this:

```py
# DataFrame that checks all possible combinations
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'up_signal1': [False, False, True, True], 
    'up_signal2': [False, True, False, True]
})


df['chk'] = df.up_signal1 & df.up_signal2

df
    up_signal1  up_signal2  chk
0   False       False       False
1   False       True        False
2   True        False       False
3   True        True        True
```